# AngularJS - Align right md-button in md-menu-bar

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I've researched this but I still can not fix this.

**I need my VTS Anketa button to be right**, while all the other buttons are aligned left.
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<md-toolbar layout="row" flex="1">
  <md-menu-bar>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button ng-href="/#/">Home</md-button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button ng-href="/#/create">Napravi anketu</md-button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button ng-href="/#/view">Pogledaj anketu</md-button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu>
       <md-button layout-align="right" ng-href="/#/delete" ng-click="delete()"> Izbrisi anketu</md-button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button id="moveright" ng-href="/#/">VTŠ Anketa</md-button>
    </md-menu>
  </md-menu-bar>
</md-toolbar>
```

I've tried adding span flex before the md-button and the md-menu, but then the button just dissapears:

```
<md-menu>
   <span flex></span>
     <md-button id="moveright" ng-href="/#/">VTŠ Anketa</md-button>
</md-menu>
```

Result:
[image]

Also, I've tried adding an id in the tag, then calling that id in the css and using text-align: right;, that also did not do anything.

Comment: Have you tried the css `float:right`?

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't do anything. The css is connected, the `color: red;` works, but moving it won't work :(. @sn3ll

Answer (score 1):

add flex to the md-menu-bar and add float:right to the id moveright

```
<md-menu-bar flex>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button ng-href="/#/">Home</md-button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button ng-href="/#/create">Napravi anketu</md-button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu>
      <md-button ng-href="/#/view">Pogledaj anketu</md-button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu>
       <md-button ng-href="/#/delete" ng-click="delete()"> Izbrisi anketu</md-button>
    </md-menu>
    <md-menu >
      <md-button id="moveright" ng-href="/#/">VTŠ Anketa</md-button>
    </md-menu>
  </md-menu-bar>
```

css:

```
#moveright {
  float: right;
}
```

it is because md-menu-bar has its maximum width in the toolbar, so you have to flex it all the way as the toolbar's width so that you can move around the items.

see codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjxwNZ

Answer (score 0):

I created a different toolbar and used  the span layout like this:

```
<md-toolbar layout="column">

  <span layout="row" layout-padding>
  <h2 class="md-toolbar-tools" style="font-family: Trebuchet MS;"> VTŠ Anketa</h2>

  <md-button ng-href="/#/" id="movebottom">Glasaj</md-button>
  <md-button ng-href="/#/create">Napravi</md-button>
  <md-button ng-href="/#/view">Pogledaj</md-button>
  <md-button ng-href="/#/delete" ng-click="delete()"> Izbriši</md-button>
  </span>
</md-toolbar>
```